# Orders of growth involving both recursion and two inner for loops

Tags: python, recursion, runtime

I have attempted the below question but I am uncertain whether I am correct or not. I have arrived at the conclusion that it is a big theta of n^2 function. My reasoning is that the inner 2 loops for i and for j will amount to a sequence of operations, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5....x -1, which can be translated into (x * x - 1) /2 by the arithmetic operation. However, the outer recursive call kind of trips me up. I am tempted to look at the outer recursive call as yet another while loop but I fought it off because it isn't exactly another while loop or for loop because x also changes. Can someone help me arrive at a better understanding of the below question?

```
    def foo(x):
        if x < 1: 
            return 'boo'
        for i in range(x): 
            for j in range(i):
                return foo(i + j)
        return foo(x-1)
```

REVISION: I just ran this code through my python interpreter and turns out it will be constant time as it is a trick question. The reason being, the return statement will just evaluate to foo(1), and then 'boo' gets outputted no matter what size of n you are at.

But----> What if I were to change my code to the following. Is the run time now theta(n^2) or theta(n^3)?

```
    def foo(x):
        if x < 1: 
            return 'boo'
        for i in range(x): 
            for j in range(i):
                print(i + j)
        return foo(x-1)
```

Comment: Please share the sample input and the desired output

Comment: inside 2 inner loops is `return` so I think you can reduce both loops to `return foo(2)` and it never stops.

Comment: Have you tried analyzing it with [recursion trees and the master method](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/lec20.html)?

Comment: @AlbertRothman, how would you apply the master method to this problem?

Comment: @cy.serenity. it is n^3 as you make n-1 recursive calls and do quadratic work outside the calls. Also your first function does not return straight away, in the outer for you loop from 0-1 considering x to be >1,  in the inner loop nothing happens on the first iteration bit the second goes from also from `return foo(i + j) -> return  foo(1)`, you then it the `return foo(x - 1) -> return foo(0)`, you reach your base case and return.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** First there was `i+i` in question but now there is `i+j` so now my answer is wrong.

---

When `x < 1` it prints 'boo' - nothing intersting.

When `x >= 1` then you can reach loops

```
for i in range(x): 
    for j in range(i):
        return foo(i+i)
```

so let `x = 1` and you have

```
for i in range(1): 
    for j in range(i):
        return foo(i+i)
```

so let `i = 0` - and you have

```
    for j in range(0):
```

and it will newer run

so let `i = 1` - and you have

```
    for j in range(1):
```

and for `j = 0` you can run

```
    return foo(2)
```

and you return to the beginnig of this description.
And you will again get `return foo(2)`. Check it on your own.

So for 'x >= 1' you always get `return foo(2)`.
So you can reduce this code to

```
def foo(x):
    if x < 1: 
        return 'boo'
    return foo(2)
```

(you will never reach `return foo(x-1)`)

You have infinite function.

(I hope I'm right)

Comment: Nope.  The second loop iteration is, indeed, with i=0, j=1, but this gives you a call for **foo(1)**, not **foo(2)**.  foo(1) drops to the final statement, where it returns **'boo'**.  As OP has now acknowledged, this is constant time.  See the excellent explanation by @Padraic Cunningham in the comments.

Comment: @Prune I checked question there was `i+i` before. And now is `i+j` so now my answer is wrong.